# Microsoft Graph APIs handling of oAuth2.0 refresh tokens

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api

What's the validity of a **refresh** token? From my observation, *refresh tokens expire in an day* and then the user has to again authenticate his/her account which is tedious and redundant. How to prevent refresh tokens from expiring or give them longevity?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/app_authorization when the access token is renewed using the refresh token, both tokens are extended.  Presumably, then, as long as the refresh token is never let to expire, this could go on indefinitely.

Comment: The question is about refresh tokens. What's there validity (since Graph APIs do not return expiry time of refresh token). And what are the suggested approaches to **refresh token is never let to expire** ?

Comment: Both tokens are extended, including the refresh token.  The strategy would be to just make sure you always refresh the access tokens.

Answer (score 0):

This article includes information about the default lifetimes of tokens issued by Azure AD:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes

There are no defaults where refresh tokens expire in one day.  They last at least 14 days minimum.  You may be experiencing a different issue.